# jQuery show function flashing briefly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am very new to web development and jQuery. I'm trying to add my first jQuery method to my code in Ruby on Rails.  I have a css class

```
.list-group-item{
  display: none;
}
```

and a JS function

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".list-group").click(function(){
  $(".list-group-item").show();
});    

});
```

I tested it with an alert, the alert appeared. When I try to run this, the list group briefly flashed then goes away immediately.  I am sure it is a simple mistake.  I have tried adding return false before the document function, no change.  Thanks for acknowledging my noob question :)

Comment: How does your html look like? Also see if you can create a demo for this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is .list-group-item a link?  If so, it sounds like the page is reloading as you don't have return false.  Need something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".list-group").click(function(){
    $(".list-group-item").show();
    return false;
  });    
});
```

What this does is stop the link from doing anything else after it shows the links with list-group-item class.

Comment: Yes.. I added return false after the wrong function the first time, that fixed it

Comment: Is there something I can add to retain the link functionality?

Comment: What are you looking to do?  Retaining the link functionality makes the page load whatever link is there unless you have javascript in the link, which is not good coding practice.  There would be no point in doing that.

Comment: The list group is in the header of my site in an unordered list, with quite a few list items containing links.  I just want the user to see the list when they click the .list-group element, with links still functioning.  I'm guessing I'll have to implement it a way.

Comment: Ok, so you need to find a pattern and add a condition in there around the return false.  If ($(this).attr('href') === "#" || $(this).attr('href') === "") { return false; }

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the `return false;` after the `show()` function...assuming the list item is a link. `return false;` prevents the default behaviour of the selector. So if it's a link, it'll prevent the link from functioning - or being fired.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".list-group").click(function(){
       $(".list-group-item").show();

       return false; // add this here
   });    
});
```